# clearInterval() using the developer tools?

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

Is there a way I can clear an *interval* using `clearInterval()` in the *console*?

If I try `window.clearInterval(interval)` I get an undefined variable error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: interval is not defined
>       at :1:15

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    console.log('test') 
}, 2000);
```

Or is, what I'm trying, not possible at all?

Comment: No you can't, unless you are debugging in console and `interval` is defined at that point..

Comment: perhaps you can inspect it when it is assigned. most browser implementations the timer handle is just a number.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao So that means, accessing variables defined in scripts can't be reached from the console?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with your example. The `interval` variable is global there, so it works fine out of the box. Just make sure to select the iframe  scope in the devtools console.

Comment: Scoped variables are not available outside, unless you expose them to global scope. In your example `interval` is not global so you can't clear it from console of course.

Comment: I am assuming you dont have setinterval id. This solution is just a hack, As id is just a number,  that is increased by 1 everytime new `setInterval` is created. You can run a for loop from 1 to 10000 or something and clear all intervals.

Comment: @Bergi What browser did you use? And how? Because if I type in the console `window.clearInterval(interval)` it doens't work (chrome)

Comment: @Red Yes, Chrome. As I said, make sure to open the console in the context of the iframe (stacksnippets.net not stackoverflow.com) - click "run code" and inspect the element is the easiest way to get there

Comment: Did you try changing the scope of the variable to global.. Define it somewhere top of the script.. outside everything.. That should be accessible I believe..

Comment: @Bergi Lol, I did now even know that :). I was using codepen.io, and it works there too using that. Thanks!! Kindly write as anwser.